# Django race condition inside a transaction

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have Django 1.11 app with PostgreSQL.
Take a look at code below.

Is it possible to have race condition there? I am afraid I could get race condition on `diff=-account.hours`. Does `transaction.atomic` save from race condition?

```
from django.db import transaction

def write_off(account_ids):
    accounts = Account.objects.filter(id__in=account_ids)
    for account in accounts:

        with transaction.atomic():
            MyLog.objects.create(
                hours=0,
                operation_type=LOG_OPERATION_WRITE_OFF,
                diff=-account.hours,
            )
            Account.objects.filter(pk=account.pk).update(hours=0)
```

Comment: From what it appears to me, your code should not work. `account` will be a `QuerySet` and not a single `Account` instance. Therefor it will not have `.hours` and `.pk`.

Comment: @KlausD. I have edited the question, thank you.

Comment: And now explain where you see a possible race condition. Where is the race?

Comment: @KlausD. in the line `diff=-account.hours`. I take `account` instance, then save `account.hours` to `MyLog`, and then set `account.hours=0`. Could the value of `account.hours` be changed after I create `MyLog` with outdated value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transaction.atomic() means that all your objects are created/saved in a single transaction, or none of them are. It does not prevent the accounts being modified by another request.

You could look at [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update):

```
def write_off(account_ids):
    with transaction.atomic():
        accounts = Account.objects.select_for_update().filter(id__in=account_ids)
        for account in accounts:
            MyLog.objects.create(
                hours=0,
                operation_type=LOG_OPERATION_WRITE_OFF,
                diff=-account.hours,
            )
        accounts.update(hours=0)  # use fewer queries by updating all accounts at once
```

Comment: Updating all accounts at once is not a good idea, because if one update fails, all updates would be rolled back.

Comment: You can rearrange the code to suit your needs. Note that `select_for_update` *must* be inside an atomic block.